# std::pow(x, 2) vs x * x assembly difference for integer arguments with GCC/Clang -O3

Tags: c++, std, cmath

For `float` arguments, fully optimized GCC/Clang assembly code is the same for `std::pow(x,2)` and `x*x`. However, for `int` arguments, there is a difference in the assembly. What is the reason for this extra assembly for `int` `std::pow` specification? My code does milions of such operations, so does it make sense to replace all `std::pow(x,2)` where `x` is `int` with `x*x` for performance reasons?

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/fGdsxM99x)

Comment: there is no integer overload for `std::pow` so `std::pow(x,2)` would be equivalent to `int((float)x*(float)x)`

Comment: See the docs for [std::pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). There is no standard overload for (int, int). So `std::pow` converts you ints to doubles first. Edit: only the first argument is converted to floating point, since there is a (float, int) overload.

Comment: _does it make sense to replace all std::pow(x,2) where x is int with x*x for performance reasons?_ Yes it does.  And not only for performance reasons.

Comment: My recommendation: declare globally a `template<class T> inline T square(T value) {return value*value; }` and use it instead of `pow`.

Comment: YES, YES, YES. You should never, ever, use `pow` for calculations for integers.

Comment: @prapin I am already doing exactly that, but I just wanted to make sure if that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Other than performance reasons, you may avoid overflows, but still have an accurate result using something like `auto sq(int x) { return static_cast<long long>(x) * x; }`

Comment: Minimally, the `pow()` requires a function call overhead and return; minimally a branch (call) and (return).  The `(x * x)` usually takes one instruction.  Also, the branch may cause a reload of the processor's instruction cache.  The `(x * x)` doesn't reload the instruction cache or pipeline.  In this simple example, the `pow` is less efficient than the multiply.  Many compilers, at higher optimizations, may recognize the pattern and make the substitution for you.